# Delphi replace a line

Tags: delphi

I have a .txt file and I want to replace a line with a new one. These are the steps:

1. Read in the .txt file
2. Save Source to a TStringList
3. Modify some data in a particular line
4. Save the new data back to the original file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
var
  Strings: TStringList;
....
Strings := TStringList.Create;
try
  Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);
  Strings[LineIndex] := NewValue;
  Strings.SaveToFile(FileName);
finally
  Strings.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

With newer Delphi's you can get the contents of a file as an array of strings in a single call `TFile.ReadAllLines()`.

```
program TestModifyLine;  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses Types,IoUtils;

procedure ModifyLine(fn:string;Index:integer;NewText:String);
var lines:TStringDynArray;
begin
  lines := TFile.ReadAllLines(fn);
  lines[Index] := NewText;
  TFile.WriteAllLines(fn,lines);
end;

begin
  ModifyLine('test.txt',12,'hello');
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to waste memory loading the entire source file at one time, you can use [`TStreamReader`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStreamReader) and [`TStreamWriter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TStreamWriter) to read/write the files one line at a time, modifying the desired line after reading it and before writing it.

```
Var
  Reader: TStreamReader;
  Writer: TStreamWriter:
  Line: String;
  LineNum: Integer;
Begin
  Reader := TStreamReader.Create(...);
  Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(...);
  While not Reader.EndOfStream do
  Begin
    Line := Reader.ReadLine;
    Inc(LineNum);
    If LineNum = ... Then
    Begin
      ...
    End;
    Writer.WriteLine(Line);
  End;
  Writer.Free;
  Reader.Free;
End;
```

Comment: That's going to make it hard to meet this requirement: *Save the new data back to the original file*

Comment: Not that hard. Save to a temp file first, then delete the original file, then rename the temp file to the original filename. Takes 2 extra lines of code, and it is safer anyway since the original is not overwritten unless the save is fully successful first, thus the file is not corrupted if something goes wrong. If an error occurs, the temp file can be deleted, preserving the original.

Comment: No need to tell me. Obviously I know that. That information should appear in the answer.